# Power Series $x^2+x^3+x^5+x^7+x^{11}+x^{13}+...$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, power-series

I want to find the domain of convergance of this power series:

$$x^2+x^3+x^5+x^7+x^{11}+x^{13}+...$$

I wrote it as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{p_n}$ while $p_n$ is $n$'th the smallest prime.

How can I determine its domain?

We know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n}$ domain is $-1<x<1$, is there any connection between those two?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Are you sure that this question is a duplicate? CalculusLover seems to be asking about the radius of convergence, whereas the post that you link is about analytic continuation as far as I can see.

Comment: @Joe In the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754737/is-there-a-way-to-analytically-extend-x2x3x5x7-cdotsxp-n-cdots) it is explained that the radius is $1$, but yes, it is more about the analytic continuation. So it is not a duplicate (but helpful).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x=1$, the series diverges, and therefore the radius of convergence cannot be greater than $1$.

On the other hand, if $0<x<1$, then$$x^2+x^3+x^5+x^7+\cdots<x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots=\frac x{1-x},$$and therefore the series converges.

So, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: What about if $-1<x<0 \, ?$

Comment: Then, by my argument, it converges absolutely. Therefore, it converges.

Comment: Thank you! Did you mean $x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...$? And also, why if a power series is less than a convergent power series, that means they share the same radius?

Comment: Yes, I meant that. And **no**, if a power series is less than a convergent power series, that does **not** mean that they share the same radius.

Comment: So why is the radius of converges is $1$ in this case?

Comment: Because it cannot be greatar than $1$ and because your series converges whenever $|x|<1$.

Comment: I understand now, thanks a lot!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I see that you begin this answer with 'If $x=1$, the series diverges, and therefore the radius of convergence cannot be greater than $1$.' By this statement you seem to imply that the interval for which the series converges has to be connected—for example, no power series converges when $-1 < x < 1$, and $2<x<3$. Am I understanding you correctly, and if so, is there a proof that the interval for which the series converges has to be connected?

Comment: A standard fact about power series of the type $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ (that is, power series centered at $0$) is that if such a power series converges at some $x_0$, then it converges at every $x_1$ such that $|x_1|<|x_0|$. It follow from this that if it diverges at $x_0$, then it also diverges at every $x_1$ such that $|x_1|>|x_0|$. And it follows from these two facts that the set of numbers at which the series converge is $\{0\}$, $\Bbb R$ or, for some number $r>0$, one of the intervals $(-r,r)$, $(-r,r]$, $[-r,r)$, or $[-r,r]$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Thank you, that's a very nice explanation! Is there a book that you would recommend that covers a proof of this fact? (By the way, I did not get a notification that you commented.)

Comment: See [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch6.pdf), for instance (I'm talking about theorem 6.2).